# Trigonometric identity of $\cos \left (\frac {\theta}{3}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, roots, cubics

I was trying to solve a cubic equation using trigonometric representation of Cardano's Formula solutions.

My equation looks like this:

> $$x^3-3mx+6m=0$$

I can only find $\cos(\theta)$ however to find the solutions I need $\cos \left(\frac {\theta}{3}\right)$. This can be done easily if I had numeral values for the coefficients however this is not the case here. All I know is that $m$ is a positive constant.

How can I proceed further to find it and also $\cos \left(\frac {\theta+4 \pi}{3}\right)$ and so on...

Comment: Which formula do you use? Try this reference https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cardano_formula#:~:text=A%20formula%20for%20finding%20the,px%2Bq%3D0.&text=When%20D%3E0%20all%20three,cube%20roots%20of%20imaginary%20quantities.

Comment: Cardano will not be useful here.  It may involve cube roots of complex numbers (even if the solution is real).  In fact, finding $\cos(\theta/3)$ from $\cos\theta$ is already just a cube root of a complex number, so using Cardano may even be circular arguing.

Comment: so any suggestions other than Cordano? sir, anything would help

Comment: The only suggestion is to use the formula in non-trigonometric form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x= 2\sqrt m \cos\theta$ and substitute into $x^3-3mx+6m=0$ to get

$$4\cos^3\theta - 3\cos\theta =-\frac3{\sqrt{m}} $$
which, per the identity $4\cos^3\theta - 3\cos\theta =\cos3\theta$, leads to $\cos3\theta = - \frac3{\sqrt{m}}$, or $\theta = \frac13 \cos^{-1}( - \frac3{\sqrt{m}} )+\frac{2\pi k}3$. Thus, the solutions are

$$x=2\sqrt m \cos \left(\frac13 \cos^{-1}( - \frac3{\sqrt{m}} )+\frac{2\pi k}3 \right), \>\>\>k=0,1,2$$